# Flux returns unsorted data for StepVerifier

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

I expect to receive two elements after writing three to the database. The query returns a Flux, which returns the elements unsorted.

```
@Test
fun `SUCESSFULLY query pending purchases`() {
    // arrange
    val arrived = TestDataFactory.buchungssatzEntity(
        sequentialId = 1,
        arrived = true
    )

    val pending = TestDataFactory.buchungssatzEntity(
        sequentialId = 2,
        arrived = false
    )

    val next_pending = TestDataFactory.buchungssatzEntity(
        sequentialId = 3,
        arrived = false
    )

    // act
    buchhaltungWriter.save(arrived)
    buchhaltungWriter.save(pending)
    buchhaltungWriter.save(next_pending)

    val purchases = inventoryFinder.findAllPendingPurchases()

    // assert
    StepVerifier.create(purchases)
        .expectNext(pending)
        .expectNext(next_pending)
        .verifyComplete()
}
```

This always throws

> expected value: BuchungssatzEntity(... sequentialId=2 ...); actual value: BuchungssatzEntity(... sequentialId=3 ...)

I do not want to add sorting to the database query, it's a waste of time. How can I test Flux with 'all of these elements but in any order' or should I just go for a Mono in this case, return a list and do the rest myself? Then again, that's not why I'm using reactive.

PS: Goal of this test is to verify that my Spring query language statement filters correctly.

-------- UPDATE

I solved it by using

```
StepVerifier.create(inventoryFinder.findAllPendingPurchases())
    .recordWith { listOf<PurchasesModel>() }
    .thenConsumeWhile { i: Any? -> purchases.contains(i) }
    .consumeRecordedWith{ }
    .verifyComplete()
```

Comment: any query to any database is never guaranteed any order unless you provide a `ORDERED BY` so never assume that the data is going to be retrieved as you inserted it.

Comment: I know, what's why I'm asking how I can properly test that in a reactive env

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do that is to use the `thenConsumeWhile` operator along with `expectNextCount`. If there is any element in the sequence that doesn't match, the StepVerifier will error.

In Java:

```
List<Item> pendingItems = List.of(pending, next_pending);

Flux<Item> items = inventoryFinder.findAllPendingPurchases();

StepVerifier.create(items)
        .expectNextCount(2) //expecting 2 elements
        .verifyComplete();

StepVerifier.create(items)
        .thenConsumeWhile((i) -> pendingItems.contains(i)) // check if element was expected
        .verifyComplete();
```

Comment: That does not work : / Fails with the same error message, I guess it's expecting it to arrive in the same order. So your solution seems to be exactly mine but you're passing a list instead of two explicit `next` calls

Comment: @nykon You are right, I have updated my answer.

Comment: It's still not working but I get the idea. Now I get a `expected: onComplete(); actual: onNext(BuchungssatzEntity(id=c637` but I think the direction is the right one

Comment: @nykon Could you post your code? You are expecting three elements, so you should have `.expectNextCount(3)`

Comment: Sorry for the delay - current code can be found here: https://github.com/rainerknabenbauer/ecommerce-bay/blob/main/backend/src/test/kotlin/de/einsupershop/ecommerce/inventory/dao/InventoryFinderTest.kt

Comment: Change ` StepVerifier.create(purchases)
            .expectNextCount(2)
            .verifyComplete()` to ` StepVerifier.create(purchases)
            .expectNextCount(3)
            .verifyComplete()`

Comment: You are expecting 3 elements.

Comment: I'm expecting 2 elements - behind 'findAllPendingPurchases()' is a Spring Query Language statement `return buchhaltungRepository.findByArrivedFalse()` which will return only arrived = false => 2 elements. That's what all this is about, verifying that it returns two elements.

Comment: Btw this query does work. The orders are being displayed in the UI accordingly. I just cannot possibly write a test for that, that drives me nuts.

Comment: Try to  .log() the chain to find out what the additional element is.

Comment: What did work was 

StepVerifier.create(contentBuilderService.getActiveClinics())
            .recordWith { listOf<BasicClinicModel>() }
            .thenConsumeWhile { i: Any? -> clinics.contains(i) }
            .consumeRecordedWith{ }
            .verifyComplete()